# text file to csv conversion how to get ride of split lines in input file

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to read a text file which has split lines randomly generated at column 28th from a third party.
When I conver to csv it is fine but, when I feed the files to Athena, it is not able to read because of split.
Is there a way to fine the CR here and put it back as other lines are?

Thanks,
SM

This is a code snippet :

```
import pandas as pd
add_columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"...."col59"]

res = pd.read_csv("file_name.txt", names= add_columns, sep=',\s+', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(res)

df.to_csv('final_name.csv', index = None)
```

file_name.txt

```
99,999,00499013,X701,,,5669,5669,1232,,1,1,,2,,,,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2400,1232,LXA,,<<line is split on column 28>>
2,5669,,,,68,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,71,
99,999,00499017,X701,,,5669,5669,1160,,1,1,,2,,,,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2400,1160,LXA,,1,5669,,,,,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,71,
99,999,00499019,X701,,,5669,5669,1284,,1,1,,2,,,,0,0,0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,2400,1284,LXA,,2,5669,,,,66,,,1,,,,,,,,,,,,71,
```

I have tried `str.split` but, no luck.

Comment: Does this happen to all lines or only to the first line? I don't see how `str.split` is relevant here...

Comment: I see CRLF on all the lines but, not on the others that are split up. Perhaps I should have asked how to detect others that don't have CRLF in the text file!

Comment: _"but not on the lines that are split up"_: `\n` (or `\r\n` on Windows) _is_ the line separator. You can't have a new line without that character. What do you see on the lines that are split up? Are you sure it isn't the same line split over multiple rows of your display due to text wrapping by your editor?

Comment: I checked in Notepad++ that where it showed CRLF

343,sdfdf,,,,<nothing shows here, it cont to next line>
dfdfd,df,5555CRLF
...
3454,RRT,GHHCRLF

Answer (score -1):

If you are able to convert it successfully to CSV using pandas, you can try to save it as a CSV to feed into Athena.